# "App::getLocale()" returns default language instead of current in custom service provider

Tags: php, laravel

I'm making a js localizator using service provider, and I need to get current locale to fetch current lang translations and pass to js. Everything works, but App::getLocale() keeps returning default app language.

I tried to do this using both middlware and view composer based on others issue threads in laracasts and stackoverflow, but nothing helps.
Here's links

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/get-current-locale-in-app-service-provider

[Getting locale language at provider class in Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42241782/getting-locale-language-at-provider-class-in-laravel)

[Laravel get getCurrentLocale() in AppServiceProvider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49204761/laravel-get-getcurrentlocale-in-appserviceprovider)

```php
class JstranslateServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider 
{ 
    protected $langPath; 

    public function __construct() 
    {   
        $locale = App::getLocale();
        $this->langPath = resource_path('lang/'.$locale);
        dd($locale);
    }
}
```

`dd($locale);` output is always `'en'`, despite the current language.

I made js localization using this guide [Link](https://pineco.de/using-laravels-localization-js/), it seems to be working for them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting locale in boot and putting everything in composer solved my issue.

```
public function boot()
{   
    Cache::forget('translations');
    view()->composer("layouts.app", function () {
        $locale = App::getLocale();
        if($locale == 'us')
            $locale = 'en';
        $this->langPath = resource_path('lang/'.$locale);
        Cache::rememberForever('translations', function () {
            return collect(File::allFiles($this->langPath))->flatMap( function ($file) {
                return [
                    ($translation = $file->getBasename('.php')) => trans($translation),
                ];
            })->toJson(JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this outside of a constructor in the Service Provider.

These classes are instantiated before Laravel does anything so it is likely whatever you have written in your middleware/view composer hasn't taken affect.

Instead you should be doing this either in the `boot` or `register` method.

Comment: Just tried in both functions. It's the same result 
`public function register()
    {
        $locale = App::getLocale();

        dd($locale);
    }`

Comment: And how are you setting the locale, can you share the code?

Comment: I also tried that with middleware and view composer

Comment: Yes but can you please share the code you have written to do this?

Comment: `Route::get('locale/{locale}', function($locale){
        Session::put('locale', $locale);
        return redirect()->back();
    });` 
The route gets url from app.blade.php.
I also tried to put there `App::setLocale($locale)` but it doesn't work either

Comment: I made js localization using this guide, it seems to be working for them [link](https://pineco.de/using-laravels-localization-js/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Lumen version 5.8 and figured out how to get the current locale:

```
app('translator')->getLocale();
```